# Setting attribute inside Link function AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm wondering what is the best way to set an attribute inside a link function when creating a custom directive. We have 2 options:

1.

```
function Link(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
  element[0].setAttribute("attName","attValue");
}
```

2.

```
function Link(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
  attrs.$set("attName","attValue");
}
```

Both ways seem to set the attribute on the element just fine. Can someone please tell me if they reach the same result? Are there caveats to be aware of? Thanks..